# Quantifiers in a regular expression used with awk behave unexpected

Tags: regex, bash, awk, gawk

I want to process this list: (Of course this is just an excerpt.)

```
    1   S3 -> PC-8-Set
    2   S3 -> PC-850-Set
    3   S3 -> ANSI-Set
    4   S3 -> 7-Bit-NRC
    5   PC-8-Set   -> S3
    6   PC-850-Set -> S3
    7   ANSI-Set   -> S3
```

This is what I did:

`awk -F '[[:blank:]]+' '{printf ("%s ", $2)}' list`

This is what I got:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Now I thought the quantifier `+` is equivalent to `{1,}`, but when I changed the line to

`awk -F '[[:blank:]]{1,}' '{printf ("%s ", $2)}' list`

I got just blanks and the whole line was read to $1.

Can someone explain this behaviour please? I'm thankful for every answer!

[image]

Comment: I see no difference with either command.  Are you using `GNU awk`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to escape the braces?

Comment: @SQB I tried. I just got these warnings:

Comment: `gawk: warning: escape sequence `\{' treated as plain `{'`

Comment: I think the only explanation is an old version.  Plain old awk works fine for both of your invocations on a Mac BTW.  What version of gawk do you have?

Comment: @Ray Toal: How do I find out which version I have?

Comment: Bug? The developers of your awk perhaps have no test case for this in their regression test suite.

Comment: @SQB POSIX says awk's regexes are ERE's.  Braces are live. The argument to `-F` is an `ERE`. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/awk.html

Comment: From Gawk home page: "Bug reports and feature suggestions for gawk should be sent to bug-gawk@gnu.org."

Comment: @Kaz Thanks for your suggestion, but with my experience level, I wouldn't dream of finding a bug in gawk ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
awk --re-interval -F '[[:blank:]]{1,}' '{printf ("%s ", $2)}' list
```

> `--re-interval`
>
> Allow interval expressions (see Regexp Operators) in regexps. This is now gawk's default behavior. Nevertheless, this
>   option remains both for backward compatibility, and for use in
>   combination with the `--traditional` option.

Comment: `--posix` may also work.  `gnu awk` does not work default with `interval expression` you need to tell it to do so.

Comment: Nice that it works.  I have not seen use of `interval expression` in `field separator` before..

Comment: If it's gawk's default behavior, why does it need to be specified explicitly. Bugaboo.

Comment: Its `gawk's` default behavior to `not` use `interval expression`, so you need to tell it to use it.

Comment: @Jotne Got it. The key is that the command is executed with the old awk, but the documentation is for the new behavior.

Comment: @Kaz  You that is correct. Not sure why they have removed a function like this??

Comment: @Jotne Removed? Sorry, I don't follow. The default behavior after Gawk 3.1.8 is to support the expressions by default. Not supporting them by default is old behavior: good for ancient programs that expect `{` to be literal, but failing to conform to modern POSIX which specifies ERE's everywhere for awk.

Comment: @Kaz Not removed as in gone, but some hidden.  You need to specify that you like to use them by adding `--re-interval` or `--posix`  I would prefer that they worked with out this option parameters.

Comment: @Jotne But they are not hidden now; they changed that default three years ago.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a Gawk which is from before this November 2010 commit, found by `git bisect`.

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/commit/?id=40b3741f63c19e38077d57f4ce4737916ec5073e

The change indeed hinges on the defaulting behavior with respect to intervals, which become on by default (as POSIX requires them to be).

It looks like the `--re-interval` option becomes relegated only for use with `--traditional`; i.e. that if `--traditional` is enabled, then support for `{m,n}` goes away, but can be selectively brought back with `--re-interval`.

In your version, `{m,n}` is unrecognized by default, with or without `--traditional`.  This is true up to this commit:

```
commit 00ef0423acd97cb964a2bae54c93a03a8ab50e5e
Author: Arnold D. Robbins <arnold@******>
Date:   Fri Jul 16 14:55:10 2010 +0300

    Move to 3.1.8.
```

and you're behind that still, on 3.1.5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I must admit, that I don't fully understand everything you write here. The only thing I'd like to add is, that I'm not administrator on the mentioned system, so I can't update gawk.

Comment: @Nil-o-mat What it all means is that the awk language has changed. Once it was a program running on Unix systems. Along with Unix, it changed over the years and became standardized by POSIX. This creates the problem that some old awk programs need certain old behaviors, or they break. For instance, some program may depend on the `{` character not being special in a regular expression. POSIX says that all awk regexes are Extended Regular Expressions (ERE's) in which `{` is live.  So then GNU Awk tries to cater to both requirements somehow by a combination of defaults overrrideable with options.

Comment: Hmmm, that makes sense. So basically it is a legacy problem... Thanks, for giving me some context. Always intersting to know.